# Weird Lines Between Divs with Animation

Tags: html, css

I am making a CSS pie that translates 1/4 of the pie and changes its color when it is hovered over. However, there are weird lines appearing between the pie pieces during the transition. At first these lines were appearing even when the animation was not occuring. But, I fixed that with `will-change: transform`. Any help is appreciated. Here's my code:

```css
body, html {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  will-change: transform;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
} 

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background: #333;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.circle:hover {
  background: #00AABB;
}

.circle-1:hover {
  transform: translate(-5px, -5px);
}

.circle-2:hover {
  transform: translate(5px, -5px);
}

.circle-3:hover {
  transform: translate(-5px, 5px);
}

.circle-4:hover {
  transform: translate(5px, 5px);
}

.circle-1 {
  -moz-border-radius: 90px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 90px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 90px 0 0 0;
}

.circle-2 {
  left: 90px;
  -moz-border-radius: 90px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 90px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 90px 0 0;
}

.circle-3 {
  top: 90px;
  -moz-border-radius: 90px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 90px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 90px;
}

.circle-4 {
  top: 90px;
  left: 90px;
  -moz-border-radius: 90px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 90px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 90px 0;
}
```

```html
<main class="container">
  <div class="circle circle-1"></div>
  <div class="circle circle-2"></div>
  <div class="circle circle-3"></div>
  <div class="circle circle-4"></div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making each sector `1px` larger than half the container will make them overlap slightly and you'll get rid of the artefacts.
If you think the remaining distance in hovered state is too small, increase the `transition` values by `1px` as well:

```css
body, html {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  will-change: transform;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
} 

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 91px;
  height: 91px;
  background: #333;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.circle:hover {
  background: #00AABB;
}

.circle-1:hover {
  transform: translate(-6px, -6px);
}

.circle-2:hover {
  transform: translate(6px, -6px);
}

.circle-3:hover {
  transform: translate(-6px, 6px);
}

.circle-4:hover {
  transform: translate(6px, 6px);
}

.circle-1 {
  -moz-border-radius: 90px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 90px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 90px 0 0 0;
}

.circle-2 {
  left: 90px;
  -moz-border-radius: 90px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 90px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 90px 0 0;
}

.circle-3 {
  top: 90px;
  -moz-border-radius: 90px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 90px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 90px;
}

.circle-4 {
  top: 90px;
  left: 90px;
  -moz-border-radius: 90px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 90px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 90px 0;
}
```

```html
<main class="container">
  <div class="circle circle-1"></div>
  <div class="circle circle-2"></div>
  <div class="circle circle-3"></div>
  <div class="circle circle-4"></div>
</main>
```